# What is your favorite ADE-style classification?

Tags: ade-classifications, big-list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ADE type Dynkin diagrams](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6781/ade-type-dynkin-diagrams)

What is your favorite ADE-style classification? 
Here ADE style is to be understood in a very broad sense. A classification which is not precisely ADE, but roughly related is fine. For example simple complex Lie algebras, or affine Weyl groups would be okay.

Comment: Isn't this question just a subjective version of this one? http://mathoverflow.net/questions/6781/ade-type-dynkin-diagrams

Comment: I agree with jc: this question is a duplicate.  (Also the linked to question does not use the word "favorite", the usage of which in a MO question I have come to deprecate.)

Comment: Okay, you are right, I did not spot this question before.

Answer (score 8):

Electric [plugs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power_plugs_and_sockets)!! It has a few more extra types, exactly as your simple complex Lie algebras...

Comment: Nice example :)

Comment: It's more an AC/DC style classification